# Проблема с HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, c#

Доброе время суток.

Имеется HTML страница. В ней код

```
<h1 id="story_title">{То, что мне нужно выдернуть}
<span class="vote">
```

Код такой.

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(currStoryHTML);
        HtmlNodeCollection hnNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[id=" + '"' + "story_title" + '"' + "]//span[class=" + '"' + "vote" + '"' + "]");
```

nhNode всегда null, никогда не возвращает нужного. Что делать?

Comment: Вам нужно выдернуть содержимое тэга span? Приведите пример HTML и того, что нужно получить.

Answer (score 2):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(currStoryHTML);
    HtmlNodeCollection hnNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[id='story_title']);
```

дальше можно или взять childrena, если его индекс всегда известен. или можешь еще раз провести ту же операцию.

```
 HtmlNodeCollection hn=hnNode.SelectNodes(//span[class='vote']");
```

в таком варианте можно протестить и найти где ошибка.
Или в одну строку

```
HtmlNodeCollection hnNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h1[id='story_title']).SelectNodes(//span[class='vote']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с одним слешем

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
 "/h1[id=" + '"' + "story_title" + '"' + "]/span[class=" + '"' + "vote" + '"' + "]");
```

и @ перед атрибутами

а вообще во время отладки в окне quick watch можете поиграться

1. Сначала ставите Breack point на этой строке
2. Жмёте CTRL+ALT+Q
3. вставляете htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/h1");

Comment: Не помогает.
Решил вытаскивать имя из заголовка. Путем @"//title"